# Can't connect to ws using Tinder Scarlet

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket

Trying to test connection to my ws, but server does not see any connection.
I think i miss something, could u tell me what did i miss?

Logs:

D/Connection$connect: Should Connect

D/Connection$connect: WaitingToRetry

D/Connection$connect: On WebSocket Connection Failed

D/Connection$connect: Should Connect

D/Connection$connect: WaitingToRetry

D/Connection$connect: On WebSocket Connection Failed

There is my code:

In MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Connection.connect()
}
```

Object(singleton)

```
object Connection {
    fun connect() {

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()

        val protocol = OkHttpWebSocket(
            okHttpClient,
            OkHttpWebSocket.SimpleRequestFactory(
                { Request.Builder().url("ws://someURL").build() },
                { ShutdownReason.GRACEFUL }
            )
        )

        val configuration = Scarlet.Configuration(
            streamAdapterFactories = listOf(RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
        )

        val scarletInstance = Scarlet(protocol, configuration)

        val webSocketService = scarletInstance.create<WebSocketService>()

    webSocketService.observeStateTransition()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe({ stateTransition ->
            val event = stateTransition.event
            val description = when (event) {
                is Event.OnLifecycleStateChange -> when (event.lifecycleState) {
                    LifecycleState.Started -> Timber.d("On Lifecycle Start")
                    LifecycleState.Stopped -> Timber.d("On Lifecycle Stop")
                    LifecycleState.Completed -> Timber.d("On Lifecycle Terminate")
                }
                is Event.OnProtocolEvent -> {
                    when (stateTransition.toState) {
                        is State.WillConnect -> Timber.d("WaitingToRetry")
                        is State.Connecting -> Timber.d("Connecting")
                        is State.Connected -> Timber.d("Connected")
                        is State.Disconnecting -> Timber.d("Disconnecting")
                        State.Disconnected -> Timber.d("Disconnected")
                        State.Destroyed -> Timber.d("Destroyed")
                    }
                }
                Event.OnShouldConnect -> Timber.d("Should Connect")
            }
        }, {
            e ->
            Timber.e(e)
        })

    webSocketService.observeWebSocketEvent()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe({
            event ->
            val description = when(event){
                is WebSocketEvent.OnConnectionOpened -> Timber.d("On WebSocket Connection Opened")
                is WebSocketEvent.OnMessageReceived -> Timber.d("On WebSocket NewMessageUpdate Received")
                is WebSocketEvent.OnConnectionClosing -> Timber.d("On WebSocket Connection Closing")
                is WebSocketEvent.OnConnectionClosed -> Timber.d("On WebSocket Connection Closed")
                is WebSocketEvent.OnConnectionFailed -> Timber.d("On WebSocket Connection Failed")
            }
        },
            {
                Timber.e(it)
            })


    }
}
```

Interface

```
interface WebSocketService {
@Receive
fun observeStateTransition(): Flowable<StateTransition>

@Receive
fun observeWebSocketEvent(): Flowable<WebSocketEvent>
}
```

Comment: change: 

 `webSocketService.observeWebSocketEvent()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({
                Timber.d("connected to web socket")
            },{
          Timber.e(it)  })`

Comment: then check your logs

Comment: @a_local_nobody Edited, also added logs

Comment: ahh, i was hoping you'd find an error message through that

Comment: @a_local_nobody
I can connect using this example https://gist.github.com/SheptunovaAA/90b9cb9388420cd028aa5dab3d754252
But i cant connect using Scarlet.
I mean, server works and i can connect to it with Android

Comment: no clue unfortunately, i've never worked with this before :D I just thought you might get an idea through the logs you missed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use Scarlet with WS:// by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your Manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i used ws:// but Scarlet, as i recognized, works only with wss:/

Comment: Scarlet works with ws://. You just have to add 'android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"' to your Manifest file.